# Firebase: Check Current Storage Size

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

How to check used file size from the Firebase Storage? Is there any notification if I'm almost the limit of my storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're working on adding a usage tab and developer notifications to the Storage section of the Firebase Console, but both efforts are in progress and we can't give a date on when they might complete. I recommend following our [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases) and our [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk) for the latest.